# Is there any Reason for a Web Page (aspx) to Implement the IHttpModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any scenario s where I would want to Implement `IhttpModule` ?
I want to invoke some code on `BeginRequest`   :

So I did this :

```
public partial class ServerTransferThings : System.Web.UI.Page , IHttpModule
{
 ....
 public void Init(HttpApplication context)
 {
     context.BeginRequest += lalala;
 }
 void lalala(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }
}
```

But it doesn't work.  I think it's too early stage becuase the `beginRequest` executes  before the `Page` object creation .

*Am I right* ?

Is the solution to create a DLL which implements the IHttpModule and then use the events ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's quite a code smell. Pages are far enough down the pipe you can't access `BeginRequest`.

If you want an `HttpModule`, you can create a class in your project and implement them there. You will have to configure them in the `web.config`.